# Grothendieck's in-spirit-category-theoretic functional analysis?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ct.category-theory, soft-question, ho.history-overview

I heard several times (for instance in [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhWHxiqQzrI&ab_channel=InstitutdesHautes%C3%89tudesScientifiques%28IH%C3%89S%29) [general](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmcbm5FxRJE&ab_channel=GraduateMathematics) lectures) that Grothendieck did *functional analysis* before he started doing algebraic geometry and category theory. It is said that at the time he did functional analysis, he didn't yet know what a category is, but his thinking was already very category-theoretic. For instance, I think McLarty roughly said in the linked lecture (although I don't recall the time stamp) that Grothendieck implicitly came up himself with the notion of a universal property and characterized some notions of tensor product in functional analysis via universal properties.

**Question:** Which theorems concretely did Grothendieck prove in functional analysis which are "category-theoretic" in spirit? How do these statements connect to more traditional functional analysis? (What I mean by the second question is for example: when he proved that some tensor products have a specific universal property, in which way did he apply that to solve concrete problems in functional analysis?)

I know that this question is not very concrete and rather historical (I apologize for that -- added the soft-question tag), but it's something I was wondering about when listening to these lectures, and maybe someone knows something interesting and more concrete to say.

Answer (score 7):

I am by no means an expert in the field of functional analysis, but I found some references that might be interesting and could serve as an answer (perhaps better called a soft answer).
The [following article by F. Bombal](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228543966_ALEXANDER_GROTHENDIECK%27S_WORK_ON_FUNCTIONAL_ANALYSIS) describes some of Grothendieck's work on functional analysis.

One of the main theorems mentioned is the *Kernel Theorem*. Grothendieck's approach to this theorem was via *nuclear spaces*, creating a general framework from which the theorem follows as something self-evident.
As I understand it, this is where Grothendieck used the universal properties of the tensor products the OP mentions.
About Grothendieck's proof of the Kernel Theorem, Bombal writes:

> By the way, this is a typical example of Grothendieck's way of doing
> mathematics: put the problem in a more general setting and find a general
> theory (usually, very deep and far-reaching) which contains the solution
> of the initial problem as a particular case.

In another passage, Bombal makes more explicit mention of functorial methods in [Grothendieck's *Sur Les Applications Lineaires Faiblement Compactes D'Espaces Du Type C(K)*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/sur-les-applications-lineaires-faiblement-compactes-despaces-du-type-ck/0850CAB07259076BF182429A9879C293):

> ... the article emphasizes the "functorial" point of view of
> Grothendieck: In order to study the structure of some mathematical object,
> you have to look at the behavior of the morphisms on and into it. This
> was quite usual in some parts of Mathematics, but not so in Analysis.